# overflow:visible not working in <th> IE 7,8

Tags: html, css

I can't get IE to spill the image on the top border of a . I set the top-margin of the image to negative value and set the overflow of the  to visible:

```
#th_id img {
    margin-top: -25px;
}

#th_id {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

I also tried setting the tr, tbody, table, and the div container of the table to overflow:visible but I still see a truncated image instead of the image spilling on the table border. Firefox seems to display it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it work in IE 7.

> try to add position:relative.
> My code looks like this.

```
#th_id img {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -25px;
}

#th_id {
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

> hope it helps..